# BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'articleRepository' defined in

Tags: java, spring, jpa, javabeans

I am making a simple Spring application. And I keep getting this error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'articleController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'articleRepository': Error creating bean with name 'articleRepository' defined in com.example.work.repositories.ArticleRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.example.work.models.Article
```

Here is my Article.java code

```
package com.example.work.models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity
public class Article {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String text;

    public Article(String name, String description, String text) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public Article(){

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

Here is my @SpringBootApplication class

```
package com.example.work;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class WorkApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WorkApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Here is the ArticleRepository.java

```
package com.example.work.repositories;

import com.example.work.models.Article;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface ArticleRepository extends CrudRepository<Article, Long> {
}
```

And the ArticleController.java

```
package com.example.work.controllers;

import com.example.work.models.Article;
import com.example.work.repositories.ArticleRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;


@Controller
public class ArticleController {
    @Autowired
    private ArticleRepository articleRepository;

    @GetMapping("/article")
    public String article(Model model){
        Iterable<Article> articles = articleRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("articles", articles);
        return "article";
    }
}
```

And the whole project structure:
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYA0u.png)

I have tried to find answerd for my issue, but I have only found the advice to check `@Entity` and `@Id` annotations in my models. But I do have them there, so I have no idea what to do :(

Comment: How does your package structure looks like? Make sure that the class annotated with @SpringBootApplication is in the hierarchy above all other classeses

Comment: I have checked it, it is placed above all other classes

Comment: Your model looks fine, but it's not registering.  Please provide more code so we can see what's happening.  It would be great to see your `SpringBootApplication` class and your configuration class so we can see how you've set up your project.  Without knowing more, my best guess would be that your model class is outside of your application's main package, and so it isn't being picked up by Spring.  However, further review of your Spring structure (application, configuration, file structure, etc) would help narrow down the issue.

Comment: I am not sure that my project is completely fine because I don't have a configuration class, but I have already maken Spring projects and I haven't any there too, only WebSecurityConfig, but I do not have Spring Security in this project.

Comment: In `Article` id feild is of type `int` but in `ArticleRepository` id feild is defined as Long. This could be the issue.

Comment: I have rewrited it to Long and it hasn't helped :(

Comment: Hi & Welcome! Try please: remove `@Repository` annotation... (i search evidence)

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: I removed @Repository annotation, but it didn't work((

Comment: I am currently using v3.0.0

Comment: then, gotcha! since spring-boot:3 it should be `jakarta.persistence` and not `javax.persistence`...!

Comment: Please check your classpath for this (offending, javax...) dependency ... and exclude it (stick to one version) ...https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What's-New-in-Spring-Framework-6.x

Comment: It helped! Thank you so much! You are my hero!!!

Comment: link (same issue): https://stackoverflow.com/q/74776741/592355