# Spring JPA, How can I resolve "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type" error?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to use JPA for a Java Spring Boot project. The related classes are given below. When I run the main method, I get the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.domain.example.model.Course` error multiple times, and the application crashes. I tried different configurations but none seem to work, as all of them result in the same issue. How can I resolve the `not a managed type` issue?

**Main class:**

```
package com.domain.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

// @Configuration
// @EnableAutoConfiguration// (exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
// @ComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
// @EnableJpaRepositories
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.domain.example.model"})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application .class, args);
    }
}
```

**Model class:**

```
package com.domain.example.model;

import java.util.UUID;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.Data;
// import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "course")
// @RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Course {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @Column(name = "course_id")
    private final UUID courseId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "code")
    private final Long code;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "name")
    private final String name;

    public Course(
        @JsonProperty("courseId") UUID courseId,
        @JsonProperty("code") Long code,
        @JsonProperty("name") String name
    ) {
        this.courseId = (courseId == null) ? UUID.randomUUID() : courseId;
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**The repository:**

```
package com.domain.example.repository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.domain.example.model.Course;

@Repository
public interface ICourseRepository extends JpaRepository<Course, UUID> {
    List<Course> findAllByCode(Long code); // temporary
}
```

**The service:**

```
package com.domain.example.service;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.domain.example.model.Course;
import com.domain.example.repository.ICourseRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CourseService implements ICourseService {

    private final ICourseRepository courseRepository;

    @Override
    public boolean saveCourse(Course course) {
        courseRepository.save(course);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Course> getAllCourses() {
        return courseRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Course> getAllCoursesByCode(Long code) {
        return courseRepository.findAllByCode(code);
    }
    
}
```

**The error:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.domain.example.model.Course
```

Comment: spring-boot 3?? -> `javax.persistence` -> `jakarta.persistence`

Comment: @xerx593 Can you clarify? The spring boot version is 3.0.0.

Comment: please refactor *all* (text) occurences of `javax.persistence` (in your source files)with `jakarta.persistence`

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Release-Notes -> https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What's-New-in-Spring-Framework-6.x -> "-Migration from javax to jakarta namespace for Servlet, JPA, etc."

Comment: javax.validation -> jakarta.validation (this looks already correct in your code;)

Comment: javax.servlet -> jakarta.servlet (!!!)

Comment: ... but (e.g.) *not* javax.naming .... and not (all of) `javax.xml` but (e.g./according to your classpath) `javax.xml.bind` -> `jakarta.xml.bind`

Comment: @xerx593 I made the changes you recommended and the original issue is now fixed, thank you! Now I have other errors like "org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException", but they seem easier to solve.

Comment: today's dup: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74774096/592355 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @xerx593 recommended, changing all imports from `javax.persistance` to `jakarta.persistance` solved the issue.

**Previous model class:**

```
package com.domain.example.model;

import java.util.UUID;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.Data;
// import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "course")
// @RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Course {
    // ... implementation ...
}
```

**New model class:**

```
package com.domain.example.model;

import java.util.UUID;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.Data;
// import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "course")
// @RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Course {
    // ... implementation ...
}
```